# SQL Select only missing months

Tags: sql, vertica

Notice the 2017-04-01, 2018-02-01, 2018-07-01, and 2019-01-01 months are missing in the output. I want to show only those months which are missing. Does anyone know how to go about this?

**Query:**

```
SELECT TO_DATE("Month", 'mon''yy') as dates FROM sample_sheet
group by dates
order by dates asc;
```

**Output:**

```
2017-01-01
2017-02-01
2017-03-01
2017-05-01
2017-06-01
2017-07-01
2017-08-01
2017-09-01
2017-10-01
2017-11-01
2017-12-01
2018-01-01
2018-03-01
2018-04-01
2018-05-01
2018-06-01
2018-08-01
2018-09-01
2018-10-01
2018-11-01
2018-12-01
2019-02-01
2019-03-01
2019-04-01
```

Comment: if your table doesn't contain the dates how are you going to show that?

Comment: I think maybe comparing with a temporary calendar table which contains dates between the first and last dates from the above-mentioned table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Vertica, so I wrote a working proof of concept in Microsoft SQL Server and tried to convert it to Vertica syntax based on the online documentation.

It should look like this:

```
with 
months as (
   select 2017 as date_year, 1 as date_month, to_date('2017-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as first_date, to_date('2017-01-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') as last_date
   union all
   select
      year(add_months(first_date, 1)) as date_year,
      month(add_months(first_date, 1)) as date_month, 
      add_months(first_date, 1) as first_date, 
      last_day(add_months(first_date, 1)) as last_date 
   from months
   where first_date < current_date
),
sample_dates (a_date) as (
   select to_date('2017-01-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') union all
   select to_date('2017-01-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD') union all
   select to_date('2017-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') union all
   select to_date('2017-04-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') union all
   select to_date('2017-06-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
)
select * 
from sample_dates right join months on sample_dates.a_date between first_date and last_date
where sample_dates.a_date is null
```

*Months* is a recursive dynamic table that holds all months since 2017-01, with first and last day of the month. *sample_dates* is just a list of dates to test the logic - you should replace it with your own table.

Once you build that monthly calendar table all you need to do is check your dates against it using an outer query to see what dates are not between any of those periods between *first_date* and *last_date* columns.

Comment: Please let me know if you find any syntax errors using Vertica.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a TIMESERIES of all dates between the first input date and the last input date (The highest granularity of a TIMESERIES is the day.), and filter out only the months' first days out of that; then left join that created sequence of firsts of month with your input to find out where the join would fail, checking for NULLS from the input branch of the join:

```
WITH
-- your input
input(mth1st) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2017-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-02-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-03-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-05-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-06-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-07-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-08-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-09-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-10-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-11-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-12-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-03-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-04-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-05-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-06-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-08-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-09-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-10-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-11-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-12-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-02-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-03-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2019-04-01'
)
,
-- need a series of month's firsts
-- TIMESERIES works for INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
-- so build that timeseries, and filter out
-- the month's firsts
limits(mth1st) AS (
          SELECT MIN(mth1st) FROM input
UNION ALL SELECT MAX(mth1st) FROM input
)
,
alldates AS (
  SELECT dt::DATE FROM limits
  TIMESERIES dt AS '1 day' OVER(ORDER BY mth1st::TIMESTAMP)
)
,
allfirsts(mth1st) AS (
  SELECT dt FROM alldates WHERE DAY(dt)=1
)
SELECT
  allfirsts.mth1st
FROM allfirsts
LEFT JOIN input USING(mth1st)
WHERE input.mth1st IS NULL;
-- out    mth1st   
-- out ------------
-- out  2017-04-01
-- out  2018-02-01
-- out  2018-07-01
-- out  2019-01-01
```